# jQuery using .siblings() to find value of input not returning anything

Tags: jquery

I have cards which represent various locations in my app. Each location has one card each. I'm trying to get the id the location which I've placed in a hidden input element within each card. I've tried using both .closest() and .siblings() but neither seem to return anything when I try and log to the console. Any ideas at all?

```
function getLocationData() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'php/getAllLocations.php',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      $('#location-results').empty();
      $('#adddeptlocationlist').empty();
      $('#editdeptlocationlist').empty();
      $('#edit-location-list').empty();
    let locations = data.data;
  
    
    locations.forEach(function(position){
      $('#location-results').append(`<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body" id="${position.id}">
        <div class="individual-result"><i class="fa-solid fa-map-location fa-xl"></i><h5 class="card-title record" id="one-location-name-${position.id}">${position.name}</h5></div>
        <button class="edit-location-button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editLocationModal"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
        <input class="location-id" value="${position.id}">
        <button type="button" class="delete-location-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
      </div>
      
    </div>`);
    
    $('#adddeptlocationlist').append(`<option value="${position.id}">${position.name}</option>`);
    $('#editdeptlocationlist').append(`<option value="${position.id}">${position.name}</option>`);
    $('#edit-location-list').append(`<option value="${position.id}">${position.name}</option>`);
  
  });
}
  })
  
}

function getDeptData() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/getAllDepartments.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      $("#department-results").empty();
      $("#add-employee-dept-list").empty();
      $("#editdeptlist").empty();
      $("#edit-employee-dept-list").empty();
      let departments = data.data;

      departments.forEach(function(position){


        $("#add-employee-dept-list").append(`<option value="${position.id}">${position.name}</option>`);
                    
        $("#department-results").append(
          `<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p id="location-id-${position.id}" class="department-location-id">${position.locationID}</p>
        <div class="individual-result"><i class="fa-solid fa-building fa-xl"></i><h5 class="card-title record" id="department-name-${position.id}">${position.name}</h5></div>
        <div class="individual-result"><i class="fa-solid fa-map-location"></i><h6 id="location-name-${position.id}" class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted record">${position.location}</h6></div>
        <button id="${position.id}" class="edit-location-button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editDepartmentModal" onclick="populateEditDepartmentModal(this.id);"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="delete-department-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
      </div>
      
    </div>`);
  
        
      });
    }
  })
}



function getEmployeeData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/getAll.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      let employees = data.data;
      $("#employee-results").empty();
      currentData = employees;
      console.log(employees);
      employees.forEach(function(position){

        let jobTitle;

        if (position.jobTitle == ""){
          jobTitle = "Position not allocated";
        } else {
          jobtitle = position.jobTitle;
        }

        $("#employee-results").append(`<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="individual-result"><h5 class="card-title record"><span id="first-name-${position.id}">${position.firstName}</span>&nbsp<span id="last-name-${position.id}">${position.lastName}</span></h5></div>
            <div class="individual-result"><p id="email-${position.id}">${position.email}<p></div>
            <div class="individual-result"><p id="jobTitle-${position.id}">${jobTitle}<p></div>
            <p id="one-department-id-${position.id}" class="department-id">${position.departmentID}</p>
            <div class="dept-location"><div class="individual-result"><i class="fa-solid fa-building"></i><h6 class="record" id="one-department-${position.id}">${position.department}</h5></div>
            <div class="individual-result"><i class="fa-solid fa-map-location"></i><h6 class="record" id="location-${position.id}">${position.location}</h5></div>
            
          </div>
          <button id="${position.id}" class="edit-employee-button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editEmployeeModal" onclick="populateEditModalWithCurrentInfo(this.id);"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="delete-employee-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>`);
    
      })
    }
  })
}

  getLocationData();
  getDeptData();
  getEmployeeData();

  
$('#addEmployeeForm').on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  let firstName = $('#newFirstName').val();
  let lastName = $('#newLastName').val();
  let email = $('#newEmail').val();
  let departmentID = $('#add-employee-dept-list').val();
  let jobTitle = $('#newJobTitle').val();
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'php/addNewEmployee.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      fname: firstName,
      lname: lastName,
      email: email,
      department: departmentID,
      jobTitle: jobTitle
    },
    success: function(data) {
      
      $('#addEmployeeModal').modal('hide');
      $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
      $('#addEmployeeForm').trigger('reset');
      $('#toastSuccessMessage').html(`${firstName} ${lastName} successfully added.`);
      $('#toastSuccess').toast('show');
      $("#employee-results").empty();
      getEmployeeData();
      
            
      

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $('#addEmployeeModal').modal('hide');
      $('#toastErrorMessage').html(`${firstName} ${lastName} not added.<br>${errorThrown}<br>${jqXHR}<br>${textStatus}.`);
      $('#toastError').toast('show');
    }
      
    
      
    
  });
  
});
  

$('#delete-employee-step-one-button').on('click', function(){

  let employeeToDelete = `${$('#editemployeefirstname').val()} ${$('#editemployeelastname').val()}` 

  $('#editemployeefirstname').attr("disabled", true);
  $('#editemployeelastname').attr("disabled", true);
  $('#editemployeeemail').attr("disabled", true);
  $('#edit-employee-dept-list').attr("disabled", true);
  $('#edit-employee-modal-footer').hide();
  $('#employeeToDelete').html(`Are you sure you wish to delete ${employeeToDelete}`);
  $('#delete-employee-confirmation-modal-footer').show();

});

$('#delete-employee-go-back-button').on('click', function(){
  $('#editemployeefirstname').attr("disabled", false);
  $('#editemployeelastname').attr("disabled", false);
  $('#editemployeeemail').attr("disabled", false);
  $('#edit-employee-dept-list').attr("disabled", false);
  $('#delete-employee-confirmation-modal-footer').hide();
  $('#edit-employee-modal-footer').show();
});

$('#delete-employee-proceed-button').on('click', function(){

    let employeeToDelete = `${$('#editemployeefirstname').val()} ${$('#editemployeelastname').val()}` 

    employeeID = $('#editemployeeid').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'php/deleteEmployeeByID.php',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        employeeID: employeeID
      },
      success: function(data) {
        
          $('#editEmployeeModal').modal('hide');
          $('#editEmployeeForm').trigger('reset');
          $('#toastSuccessMessage').html(`${employeeToDelete} successfully deleted.`);
          $('#toastSuccess').toast('show');
          $('.modal').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
          $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
          $('#editemployeefirstname').attr("disabled", false);
          $('#editemployeelastname').attr("disabled", false);
          $('#editemployeeemail').attr("disabled", false);
          $('#edit-employee-dept-list').attr("disabled", false);
          $('#delete-employee-confirmation-modal-footer').hide();
          $('#edit-employee-modal-footer').show();
          $("#employee-results").empty();
          $('#search-bar').val("");
          $('#search-results').hide();
          $('#search-results').html("");
          $('#employee-results').show();
          getEmployeeData();
          
          
  
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#editEmployeeModal').modal('hide');
        $('#toastErrorMessage').html(`${employeeToDelete} not deleted.<br>${errorThrown}<br>${jqXHR}<br>${textStatus}.`);
        $('#toastError').toast('show');
      }
      
    });

    
  
});

$('#edit-employee-proceed-button').on('click', function(){
  let employeeID = $('#editemployeeid').val();
  let firstName = $('#editemployeefirstname').val();
  let lastName = $('#editemployeelastname').val();
  let email = $('#editemployeeemail').val();
  let department = $('#edit-employee-dept-list').val();
  let jobTitle = $('#editJobTitle').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'php/updateEmployeeByID.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      employeeID: employeeID,
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      jobTitle: jobTitle,
      email: email,
      department: department
    },
    success: function(data) {
      
      $('#editEmployeeModal').modal('hide');
        
        $('#editEmployeeForm').trigger('reset');
        $('#toastSuccessMessage').html(`${firstName} ${lastName} successfully updated.`);
        $('#toastSuccess').toast('show');
        $('.modal').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
        $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
        $('#editemployeefirstname').attr("disabled", false);
        $('#editemployeelastname').attr("disabled", false);
        $('#editemployeeemail').attr("disabled", false);
        $('#edit-employee-dept-list').attr("disabled", false);
        $('#delete-employee-confirmation-modal-footer').hide();
        $('#edit-employee-modal-footer').show();
        $('#search-bar').val("");
        $('#search-results').hide();
        $('#search-results').html("");
        $('#employee-results').show();
        $("#employee-results").empty();
        getEmployeeData();

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $('#editEmployeeModal').modal('hide');
      $('#toastErrorMessage').html(`${firstName} ${lastName} not updated.<br>${errorThrown}<br>${jqXHR}<br>${textStatus}.`);
      $('#toastError').toast('show');
    }
      
    
      
    
  });
});

function populateEditModalWithCurrentInfo(employeeID) {

  /**let employeeFirstName = $(`#first-name-${employeeID}`).html();
  let employeeLastName = $(`#last-name-${employeeID}`).html();
  let departmentID = $(`#one-department-id-${employeeID}`).html();
  let department = $(`#one-department-${employeeID}`).html();
  let jobTitle = $(`#jobTitle-${employeeID}`).html();
  let email = $(`#email-${employeeID}`).html();*/

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'php/getPersonnelByID.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      employeeID: employeeID
    },
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data.data.department);
      console.log(data.data.personnel[0]);

      let personnel = data.data.personnel[0];
      let department = data.data.department;
      
      let email = personnel.email;
      let jobTitle = personnel.jobTitle;
      if (email == ""){
        email = "No email address";
      }

      if (jobTitle == ""){
        jobTitle = "Position not allocated";
      }
      $('#editemployeefirstname').val(personnel.firstName);
      $('#editemployeelastname').val(personnel.lastName);
      $('#editemployeeemail').val(email);
      $('#editJobTitle').val(jobTitle);

      department.forEach(function(position){
        $('#edit-employee-dept-list').append(`<option value="${position.id}">${position.name}</option>`)
      });


    }
  });

  
  

}

function populateEditLocationModal(locationID) {
  
  let locationName = $(`#one-location-name-${locationID}`).html();

  $('#updatedLocation').val(locationName);
  $('#edit-location-id').val(locationID);
}

function populateEditDepartmentModal(departmentID) {
  
  let locationID = $(`#location-id-${departmentID}`).html();
  let locationName = $(`#location-name-${departmentID}`).html();
  let departmentName = $(`#department-name-${departmentID}`).html();

  $('#updated-department-name').val(departmentName);
  $('#editdeptlocationlist').empty();
  getLocationData();
  $('#editdeptlocationlist').prepend(`<option value="${locationID}" selected>${locationName}</option>`);
  $('#department-id').val(departmentID);
}


  $('#adddeptform').on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    let deptName = $('#addDeptName').val();
    let location = $('#adddeptlocationlist').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'php/insertDepartment.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      deptName: deptName,
      location: location
    },
    success: function(data) {
      
      $('#addDepartmentModal').modal('hide');
      
      $('#adddeptform').trigger('reset');
      $('#toastSuccessMessage').html(`${deptName} successfully added.`);
      $('#toastSuccess').toast('show');
      $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
      $('#addDeptName').attr("disabled", false);
      $('#adddeptlocationlist').attr("disabled", false);
      $('#add-department-confirmation-modal-footer').hide();
      $('#add-department-modal-footer').show();
      $('#department-results').empty();
      getDeptData();
      getEmployeeData();

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $('#addDepartmentModal').modal('hide');
      $('#toastErrorMessage').html(`${deptName} not added.<br>${errorThrown}<br>${jqXHR}<br>${textStatus}.`);
      $('#toastError').toast('show');
    }
      
    
      
    
  });
  })



$('#editDepartmentForm').on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  let departmentID = $('#department-id').val();
  let updatedDepartmentName = $('#updated-department-name').val();
  let updatedLocation = $('#editdeptlocationlist').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'php/updateDepartmentByID.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      departmentID: departmentID,
      updatedDepartmentName: updatedDepartmentName,
      updatedLocation: updatedLocation
    },
    success: function(data) {
      
      $('#editDepartmentModal').modal('hide');
      
      $('#editDepartmentForm').trigger('reset');
      $('#toastSuccessMessage').html(`${updatedDepartmentName} successfully updated.`);
      $('#toastSuccess').toast('show');
      $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
      $('#edit-department-confirmation-modal-footer').hide();
      $('#edit-department-delete-button').show();
      $('#updated-department-name').attr("disabled", false);
      $('#editdeptlocationlist').attr("disabled", false);
      $('#edit-department-modal-footer').show();
      $('#department-results').empty();
      getDeptData();
      getEmployeeData();
      

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $('#editDepartmentModal').modal('hide');
      $('#toastErrorMessage').html(`${updatedDepartmentName} not updated.<br>${errorThrown}<br>${jqXHR}<br>${textStatus}.`);
      $('#toastError').toast('show');
    }
      
    
      
    
  });
})


$('#edit-department-delete-button').on('click', function(){
  
  let departmentID = $('#department-id').val();
  let departmentName = $('#updated-department-name').val();
  
  const areThereEmployeesAssignedToDept = currentData.some((element) => element.departmentID === departmentID); 

  if(areThereEmployeesAssignedToDept) {
    $('#updated-department-name').attr("disabled", true);
    $('#editdeptlocationlist').attr("disabled", true);
    $('#edit-department-delete-button').hide();
    $('#edit-department-modal-footer').hide();
    $('#departmentToEditError').html(`This department still has employees assigned to it. You must either delete these employees or assign them to another department.`);
    $('#delete-department-error-modal-footer').show();
  } else {
    $('#updated-department-name').attr("disabled", true);
    $('#editdeptlocationlist').attr("disabled", true);
    $('#edit-department-delete-button').hide();
    $('#edit-department-modal-footer').hide();
    $('#departmentToDelete').html(`Are you sure you wish to delete ${departmentName}`);
    $('#delete-department-confirmation-modal-footer').show();
  }

  /**New DELETE FUNCTION */

  /**$(document).on('click', '.delete-location-button', function() {
    let locationID = $(this).prev().val();
    console.log(locationID);   
});*/

$('.delete-location-button').on('click', function(){
  let button = $(this);
  let locationID = button.parent().attr('id');
   console.log(locationID);   
});
```

Comment: Which runs first?  `$('.delete-location-button').on('click',` or `locations.forEach(function(position){`  sounds like the on-click is running first.

Comment: Yes the `locations.forEach` etc runs first.

Comment: As long as your locations.forEach *does* run first, your code works fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/vt2mx56L/   If your `.on("click"` runs first then you'll get no events when clicking.   Please [edit] the question to include a *complete* snippet that *demonstrates* the issue.

Comment: My `locations.forEach` definitely runs first. I've updated my question with the entire code block from locations.forEach to where I declare the on click event handler. Still not working unfortunately :(

Comment: Your code *clearly* shows that the ".onclick" **runs** first, where it's located in the code is irrelevant.  You can check this with a `console.log("1")` in front of the `locations.forEach` and a `console.log("2")` in front of the .onclick.   Your `locations.forEach` is run inside an *ajax callback* so *runs* later.   You need to use event delegation:  `$(document).on("click", '.delete-location-button', function(){`

Answer (score 0):

Since the input element immediately precedes the button, you can use `prev()` to retrieve the location id, like this:

`button.prev('.location-id').val()` (or `button.prev().val()`, since it is the direct previous sibling).

BUT, it looks like you are creating `card` elements DYNAMICALLY with `append()`.

This means you cannot bind events directly to these elements, and you have to delegate the event to a static ancestor (like `document`).

This should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-location-button', function() {
    let locationID = $(this).prev().val();
    console.log(locationID);   
});
```

Comment: Oh dear, it sounds like I've gone about this the hard way. `$(document).on('click', '.delete-location-button', function() {
    let locationID = $(this).prev().val();
    console.log(locationID);   
});` hasn't worked unfortunately. Thank you though. Can I change the way I'm creating the card elements to make this work?